# Express: using trust proxy to get user IP

Tags: node.js, express, reverse-proxy

I have an express server run at port 3000. I decide to set a reverse proxy by nginx to redirect all http://test.com to http://test.com:3000.

After setting up all the stuff, I make an API to test, it is to show user IP:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    res.json({
        ip: req.ip
    });
});
```

`ip` sometimes is `127.0.0.1` while sometimes is `::1`. Since it is behind the proxy, it is correct. To my knowledge, they are equivalent so I didn't dig into it.

I add the following to show user real IP instead:

```
app.set("trust proxy", "127.0.0.1");
```

However, `ip` sometimes show correctly with my real IP but sometimes show `::1`.

I have to set to this to make it work:

```
app.set("trust proxy", "loopback");
```

Do I fix the problem correctly or I am doing dangerous hack? Also, what is the different between `127.0.0.1` and `::1`? I am very confusing. I hope someone and gives a detailed answer to make my concept clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically `127.0.0.1` is IPv4 while `::1` is IPv6. Actually, you fixed it correctly. To be more clear, you can specify the server listen only to either IPv4 or IPv6:

```
server.listen(port, "127.0.0.1"); // IPv4
```

or

```
server.listen(port, "::1"); // IPv6
```

Comment: It's fine to listen only IPv4... if the DNS record does not have any IPv6. Otherwise your website will be down for every IPv6 users